# Background process alters the static data.

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using background worker in web an application which alters the static data in the app for multiple users using the application but with a single user it runs fine.
I get errors like

1. SqlConnection does not support parallel transactions
2. System.Data error The data has been altered
3. The static dataset gets cleared gives no row at position 0

Comment: Please provide some code and a more thorough so it would be possible for the community to assist you in some fashion :)

Comment: You need to read-up on thread safety, perhaps use Thread-local-storage to ensure your background-worker has its own `SqlConnection` instance.  That said, you shouldn't be sharing database connections amongst different threads.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that you can't share non thread safe object instances across multiple threads.

If you have a single SqlConnection opend, then how can multiple threads use this single connection (e.g. one for sending while the other thread wants to receive at the same time) without causing trouble and unpredictable behaviour? 
You need to lock the resource objects or use a ThreadLocal or create each thread with its own connection to gain thread-safety. - Be aware of race conditions or deadlocks. So 'multi-thread' with care.